# Git merge and preserve original committer

Tags: git-merge

how can i preserve original commiter, when i merging changes made by another developer?
(Something like `git merge --preserve-comitter`)

`cherry-pick` is almost good, but it seems does not preserve informations about branches

Here is an image of history made by `cherry-pick`

[image]

Here is an image of history made by `merge` 
[image]

Comment: the original committer _is_ preserved, can you elaborate _what_ part of the commit history is not to your liking? E.g. show us git log after and state what it is you don't like. I suspect you are confusing _merge commits_ with the _commits merged_ (see git log --no-merges)

Comment: I posted screenshots with two repositories, which i hope explain my point. `git log --no-merges` and `git log` really returns two a bit different outputs, but it's not what itches me. If you are right and original author is really preserved, maybe i am missing some parameter for `git log` to show it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The history made by merge, shows *exactly* what you want and need:

[image]

- the commit that was merged (nicely indented and correctly attributed to Jemerin)
- the commit that *merged it* (nicely marked as 'merge' commit and correctly attributed to Vendelin)

If you want to see 'simple' flattened log, you could use git log with options (-no-merges)

Comment: Now i got your thought, sry :)